# Manipulating Ranges in Excel - Returning a Value (Error 2029)

Tags: excel, user-defined-functions, vba

I am a quite new to Excel VBA, and I come from a more... traditional programming background (Java, C). I am having issues with passing a Range Object as a parameter in my User-defined function (see below). The idea of my function is to take several parameters to complete a VLOOKUP of a filtered range.

I may have several syntax issues (I am unsure of my return type and my usage of VLOOKUP), and I would appreciate some guidance on this. See results, more information in my code:

```
Public Function GETVALUE(screen As String, strEvent As String, dataRange As Range, strDate As String) As String

'ASSUMPTION: dataRange has three columns; first column contains lookup values; Second
' column contains dates for filtering; Third column contains return values

Dim result As String

'remove irrelevant dates in dataRange; apply filter
'ASSUMPTION: This process should return a Range that is removes all Rows that does
'not have strDate in the second column
Dim newRange As Range

'RESULT: Returns #VALUE!. I know this is not the typical := syntax I see in many 
'examples but this one apparently compiles, so I use it. I comment this line out 
'and try to make the other lines below work with dummy parameters or fixed ranges
newRange = dataRange.AutoFilter(2, strDate)

'Now I try to use the newly filtered, "newRange" and use that in my VLOOKUP
'and return it.
result = [VLOOKUP("*" & screen & "/" & strEvent & "*", newRange, 3, False)]

'I can see an Error 2029 here on Result
GETVALUE = result 
'RESULT: Returns #VALUE!
End Function
```

Comment: You are missing a "Set": Set newRange = dataRange.Autofilter(2,strDate). But I don't think that will achieve what you intend. The filtered rows will still be part of newRange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VLOOKUP ignores any filtering of your data. In other words VLOOKUP will also look in the hidden rows.

I would suggest two alternative approaches:

1. Copy the visible cells of the filtered range to a new sheet and perform the lookup there:

   ```
   Set newRange = dataRange.AutoFilter(2, strDate).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
   set ws = worksheets.Add
   ws.Range("A1").Resize(newRange.Rows.Count,newRange.Columns.Count).Value = newRange.Value
   etc.
   ```

Note that this can not be done in a UDF, you would have to do it in a a Sub.

1. Store the values in dataRange in a variant array and loop to search for the required value:

   ```
   Dim arr() as Variant

   arr = dataRange.Value

   For i = LBound(arr,1) to UBound(arr,1)

       If (arr(i,2) = strDate) And (arr(i,1) LIKE "*" & screen & "/" & strEvent & "*"( Then
           GETVALUE = arr(i,3)
           Exit Function
       End If

   Next
   ```

Comment: Second solution is not easy to read, but it works beautifully! And it does not require me to use a new sheet!

Answer (score 1):

This I think causes your problem:

```
result = [VLOOKUP("*" & screen & "/" & strEvent & "*", newRange, 3, False)]
```

Replace it with this instead:

```
result = Evaluate("VLOOKUP(*" & screen & "/" & strEvent _
                   & "*, " & newRange.Address & ", 3, False)")
```

`[]` which is shortcut for `Evaluate` doesn't work on variables.
If it is a direct `VLOOKUP` like below:

```
result = [VLOOKUP(D1,Sheet1!$A:$C,3,FALSE)]
```

it will work. But if you are working with variables as in your example, you have to explicitly state it.
And take note that `Evaluate` accepts `Name` argument in a form of string.
So you simply have to concatenate all your strings and then explicitly use `Evaluate`.

**Edit1:** Additional Inputs

This will not work as well: `newRange = dataRange.AutoFilter(2, strDate)`.
To pass `Objects` to a `Variable` you need to use `Set` like this.

```
Set newrange = dataRange.AutoFilter(2, strDate)
```

On the other hand, `AutoFilter` method although returning a *`Range Object`* fails.
I'm not entirely sure if this can't really be done.
Moving forward, to make your code work, I guess you have to write it this way:

**Edit2:** Function procedures only returns values, not execute methods

```
Public Function GETVALUE(screen As String, strEvent As String, rng As Range)
    GETVALUE = Evaluate("VLOOKUP(*" & screen & "/" & strEvent & "*, " _
                         & rng.Address & ", 3, False)")
End Function
```

To get what you want, use above function in a `Sub Procedure`.

```
Sub Test()

Dim dataRange As Range, strDate As String, myresult As String

Set dataRange = Sheet2.Range("A2:E65") 'Assuming Sheet2 as property name.
strDate = "WhateverDateString"
dataRange.AutoFilter 2, strDate
myresult = GETVALUE("String1", "String2", dataRange)

End Sub
```

Btw, for a faster and less complex way of doing this, try what Portland posted.

Comment: "A value used in the formula is of the wrong data type". I forgot to mention that I am taking the data from a different sheet on the same workbook: This causes ERROR 2015: `result = Evaluate("VLOOKUP(*" & screen & "/" & strEvent & "*, " & "'Sheet2'!A2:E65" & ", 3, False)")`

Comment: Can you execute this `Debug.Print "VLOOKUP(*" & screen & "/" & strEvent & "*, " & "'Sheet2'!A2:E65" & ", 3, False)"`. What string it returns? 2015 is a `Runtime` error. Possibly, the `Vlookup` function returns an error.

Comment: The Debug code you posted prints this in the Immediate Window: `VLOOKUP(*MN/PA*, 'Sheet2'!A2:E65, 3, False)`

Comment: Thank you for the tips about Set, Debug.Print and Evaluate. :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you must write :

```
Getvalue = Application.VLookup( StringVar, RangeVar, ColumnNumberVar)
```

Vlookup needs your data to be previously ordered in alphabetical order, or it doesn't work.

Excel Developers's approach is a good one too, using a VBA Array.
I can also point the VBA functions FIND, and MATCH, wich will get you the row of searched data, and then you can pull what you need from the 3rd column of that row.

Wichever is faster depends of the size of your range.

Comment: Just a small point: data doesn't need to be sorted if you require an exact match, ie if the 4th parameter of VLOOKUP is FALSE.